# How to make a binomial expander in python

Tags: python, math

For example

```
(x + y)^4 = x^4 +(4x^3)y + (6x^2)y^2 + + 4xy^3 + y^4
```

I'm using python 3.3.2 and I don't know where to start, I need a little guidance. I'm not asking for the answer to it, just the general steps to make this program work. I've done a few other programs before, and this is probably pushing the limit on what I can do.

Comment: Might want to explain what "binomial expander" is ;)

Comment: @Haidro oops, BTW don't make me flag this as too chatty :)

Answer (score 10):

[SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) already do that for you:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x, y = sympy.symbols("x y")
>>> formula = (x + y) ** 4
>>> formula
(x + y)**4
>>> formula.expand()
x**4 + 4*x**3*y + 6*x**2*y**2 + 4*x*y**3 + y**4
```

If you need a visualization as a string with "^", you can do:

```
>>> str(formula.expand()).replace("**", "^")
'x^4 + 4*x^3*y + 6*x^2*y^2 + 4*x*y^3 + y^4'
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below can be found on [this](https://gist.github.com/siddMahen/1251061) site.

#### Usage

`python binomialexpansion.py 3`

#### Output

`x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3`

#### Code

```
import sys
 
power = int(eval(sys.argv[1]))
strpower = str(power)
coeffs = []
 
if power == 0:
    print 1
    exit()
 
if (power+1) % 2 == 0:
    turningp = (power+1)/2
    counter = 1
else:
    turningp = (power+2)/2
    counter = 2
 
for i in range(1, power+2):
    if i == 1:
        sys.stdout.write("x^"+strpower+" + ")
        coeffs.append(1)
        continue
    if i == power+1:
        print "y^"+strpower,
        coeffs.append(1)
        break
 
    if i > turningp:
        co = coeffs[turningp-counter]
        counter = counter+1
    else:
        co = ((power-(i-2))*coeffs[i-2])/(i-1)
    
    coeffs.append(co)
    sys.stdout.write(str(co))
 
    if power-(i-1) == 1:
        sys.stdout.write("x")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("x^"+str(power-(i-1)))
 
    if i-1 == 1:
        sys.stdout.write("y ")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("y^"+str(i-1)+" ")
 
    sys.stdout.write("+ ")
```